# How to set placeholder to multiple text views in one view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, placeholder

I've got a view controller which contains two text views (storyTitle and storyDescription). I've added placeholders to both text views, the code below will show you how I've done that:

```
// Setup the story title text field
func setupStoryTitleTextView() {

    storyTitle.textColor = .gray
    storyTitle.text = "Add story title"
    storyTitle.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
    self.storyTitle.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(storyTitle)

}
// Setup the storyDescription text view
func setupStoryDescriptionTextView() {

    storyDescription.text = "Description of the story"
    storyDescription.textColor = .gray
    storyDescription.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 300, right: 20)
    self.storyDescription.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(storyDescription)

}
// To remove placeholder text when the user starts typing
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    // Story title text view
    if storyTitle.textColor == .gray {
        storyTitle.text = nil
        storyTitle.textColor = .black
    }

    // Story description text view
    if storyDescription.textColor == .gray {
        storyDescription.text = nil
        storyDescription.textColor = .black
    }
}
// To bring the placeholder back when the text views don't contain any text
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    // Story title text view
    if storyTitle.text.isEmpty {
        storyTitle.text = "Add story title"
        storyTitle.textColor = .gray
    }

    // Story description text view
    if storyDescription.text.isEmpty {
        storyDescription.text = "Description of the story"
        storyDescription.textColor = .gray
    }
}
```

What happens here is that, when I tap on one text view, the placeholders in both the text views disappear, this is because both the if conditions under `textViewDidBeginEditing` are executed. How can I prevent this from happening? Any kind of help is appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by assigning **tags** to view objects (your textviews). Assign a tag with **textview.tag** = [some number] and then you can also add to your conditions something like that:

```
storyDescription.tag = 1

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.tag == 1 && storyTitle.textColor == .gray {
        storyTitle.text = nil
        storyTitle.textColor = .black
    }
}
```

And this analogue to the other textview

Comment: I would strongly discourage using the tag for this, it's not scalable, and leads to mistakes. Instead, why not just compare if `textView == storyTitle`? The tag isn't needed at all here

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Didn't knew that such a simple comparison is possible here

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, I tried @Ferdz way, it worked well :)

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal You should probably mark it as the accepted answer so others can find it too :^)

Answer (score 0):

```
// To remove placeholder text when the user starts typing
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    // Story title text view
    if storyTitle.textColor == .gray {
        storyTitle.text = nil
        storyTitle.textColor = .black
    }

    // Story description text view
    if storyDescription.textColor == .gray {
        storyDescription.text = nil
        storyDescription.textColor = .black
    }
}
// To bring the placeholder back when the text views don't contain any text
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    // Story title text view
    if storyTitle.text.isEmpty {
        storyTitle.text = "Add story title"
        storyTitle.textColor = .gray
    }

    // Story description text view
    if storyDescription.text.isEmpty {
        storyDescription.text = "Description of the story"
        storyDescription.textColor = .gray
    }
}
```

This piece of code will apply to both your TextViews. This is wrong, ideally you should use the `textView` provided in the delegate method, like so:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == .gray {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
}
// To bring the placeholder back when the text views don't contain any text
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.textColor = .gray
    }
    // You can then restore the text depending on which TextView ended the edition, for example:
    if textView == self.storyTitle {
        self.storyTitle.text = "Add story title"
    }
}
```

By the way, deciding wether or not a TextView is displaying a placeholder based on the color might not be the best way, especially if you plan on eventually supporting decorated strings. That's another discussion completely, but it will work for the time being

Comment: Well this answer isn't quite correct, because the placeholders in the text views need to be different from each other, but you are using the same placeholder, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Right, in that case just check `textView` against your IBOutlets. EG if `textView == storyDescription` show the description placeholder, but if `textView == storyTitle` show the title

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I've done, cuz you mentioned that in the comment on the previous answer, so if you can change your answer according to that then I can accept it :)

Comment: Done, please have a look at the comment in the code

Comment: Hey, the comment is fine, would you like to update your answer so that I can accept it as the correct answer?